Failed to load image to background
I'm making an application that is just front end, and for the background images of the instagram videos shown I'm doing ->
background: url(https://www.instagram.com/p/${video_id}/media/?size=m) 

, for example:
background: url(https://www.instagram.com/p/C9zFMxnR1dr/media/?size=m);

, the problem is that the image is not loading, and in the console it is being shown:

instagram.fjdo1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.29350-15/448756273_949006160245341_2706300162411218520_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_e15_p320x320&_nc_ht=instagram.fjdo 1-2.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=109& _nc_ohc=3J-YJuA1NckQ7kNvgH5VQoO&gid=8ca427d06716423fbcc40b90d2d1f6e7&edm=AGenrX8BAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AYC9mTyJvJzPwXBaHGebpHwSQf5oSBytky7PrKvxLtkK9w&oe=66B55F38&_nc_sid=ed990e:1
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOrigin

Since I don't have the server side, how do I change the cors from the front end so that this background works?

CORS is HTTP header set by server. You cannot manipulate it from the browser. If you could, what would be the purpose of it?

The only way is proxy it through your own server. No way to pull this off just on the client.

Is the op the owner of instagram? Didn’t mention that in the question. Instagram is blocking the request since it’s not performed by a whitelisted domain and a proxy will not resolve the issue.

If your server is doing the call to instagram, there is no cors problem. The cors is only necessary in the browser. You can just curl this urls or open them inside of your browser. Tried it just now on my phone.

Basically it uses a vulnerability found in Instagram image URL using googletranslate. Decrypt your url using this file. You can also just create this code in any language simple URL manipulation.
    public static string UrlDecrypt(string url)
    {
        var p = url.Split('/');
        var t = new StringBuilder();
    
        for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == 2)
            {
                t.Append(p[i].Replace("-", "--").Replace(".", "-"))
                 .Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("LnRyYW5zbGF0ZS5nb29n")))
                 .Append('/');
            }
            else
            {
                if (i != p.Length - 1)
                {
                    t.Append(p[i]).Append('/');
                }
                else
                {
                    t.Append(p[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    
        var encodedUrl = Uri.EscapeUriString(t.ToString());
        return encodedUrl;
    }

